# Travelling through one's origin country with an Interrail pass

Tags: interrail

A flexible Interrail pass includes 2 days to leave/return to your origin country. All other trips must be taken in foreign countries.

How does this hold if one wants to cross their origin country?

For example:

- Starting from Germany, to the Netherlands
- Then, wishing to visit Poland

There aren't too many ways to get from the Netherlands to Poland by train that doesn't involve crossing Germany.

Considering that the travel would bring the traveller in Germany, I don't think it would be valid, but considering that the traveller is not going to Germany, but rather to Poland, it might?

Is there an authoritative source that specifically details this case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of the Interrail terms of use, but IMO the rule against using a rail pass in one's own country is hard to circumvent, unless one has a permanent residence in a country other than one's country of citizenship (then it's possible to game the system). You can buy a separate ticket for the Germany section, or you can also fly there; Poland is well served by low-cost airlines.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed an issue. This is also valid for Sweden and a few other countries.
I would advise contact
https://eurail.zendesk.com/hc/en-001/requests/new
and request extra in/outbound legs due to your travel plan DE-NL-PL.
You will be surprised. They will give you extra leg.